# Turning points of particle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, potential-energy

> A particle of mass $m$ and energy $E<0$ moves in a one-dimensional Morse potential:
>
> $$V(x)=V_0(e^{-2ax}-2e^{-ax}),\qquad       V_0,a>0,\qquad E>-V_0.$$
>
> [image]
>
> Determine the turning points of the movement and the period of the oscillation of the particle.

I have started learning for my exam and this is one of the exercises in my textbook. 
Never dealt with this type of question, so these are my thoughts so far:

To get the turning points I was thinking of solving the equation $E=V_0(e^{-2ax}-2e^{-ax})$. I was doing the arithmetics with the absolute value of $E$. But still I couldn't seem to find the values for $x$. At the end I used Wolfram Alpha to find the values but it gave me results with complex values. Is there a simple way to solve this type of equations for $x$?

Anyway, about the period, I assume it's the time it takes for the particle to get from $x_1$ to $x_2$. But how am I supposed to approach this? How would I get a time value just out of the equation for the potential?

I hope someone can help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Energy conservation dictates
$$ E = \frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2 + V(x) = \text{const}$$
With some arithmetic it follows
$$ \dot{x} = \frac{dx}{dt} = \sqrt{2m^{-1}(E-V(x))}$$
This ODE can be solved via [separation of variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables),
yielding
$$ \int_{t_1}^{t_2}dt = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2m^{-1}(E-V(x))}}$$
The integral on the left hand side can be evaluated immediately, where $t_1$ and $t_2$ are understood as the times when the particle is at $x_1$ or $x_2$ respectively. So it is simply half the period.

Observe that the integral on the right diverges when $x$ approaches the turning point $E=V(x)$.

This method of solving Newtons equations in a 1d potential should be treated in *any* textbook on mechanics.

For a general potential it is in general hard or impossible to find the turning points in closed form. Here however, you can substitute $y=\exp(-ax)$ and solve the corresponding quadratic equation. I'll leave the explicit calculation to you.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. But I still can't seem to find $x_1$ and $x_2$ from the equation. I just can't seem to solve for x. Am I missing something?

Comment: @RafaFafa Had to think for a bit, but see my edit on how to do the calculation.

Comment: I did the calculations and got $y_{1,2}=y\pm \sqrt{e^{-2ax}+\frac{E}{V_0}}$. Can I just plug this in as boundaries instead of $x_1$ and $x_2$? Because I can't seem to solve this for x.

Comment: @RafaFafa You went wrong somewhere... Substituting $y=exp(-ax)$ yields $E/V_0 = y^2 - 2y$, which is simply a quadrativ equation in $y$ that has two solutions $y_{1,2}$ for negative $E$.

Comment: Yes, which should yield $y_{1,2}=y\pm \sqrt{y^2+\frac{E}{V_0}}$, right?

Comment: @RafaFafa No, you are _solving_ for $y$, thus the solutions cannot depend on $y$.

Comment: I'm such an idiot. $y_{1,2}=1\pm \sqrt{1+\frac{E}{V_0}}$. 

Edit: So can I assume that $y_{1,2}=e^{-ax}$ and thus getting $x_{1,2}=-\frac{1}{a}ln(1\pm \sqrt{1+\frac{E}{V_0}})$?

Comment: @RafaFafa That seems to be the solution :-)

Comment: Hmm. I can't seem to solve the integral. Not even with Wolfram Alpha. It says the integral depends on the values of some variables. But I tried it both with $E$ and $-E$, so I guess it's not about that. Is there maybe a general formula to solve this type of integral?

Comment: @RafaFafa The integral is ugly. I plugged it into Mathematica and it returned a closed expression, but I'm not sure how to obtain this by hand. You could probably do the same substitution in the integral as before. I have not done the calculation. However, if you're only interested in energies $E$ close to $-V_0$ you may expand the potential around the minimum up to second order, and approx. as a harmonic oscillator. Then you can read the frequency off. Of course this approximation becomes worse for higher values of $E$.

Comment: Okay, I did all the calculations again and started from this instead: $E=-|E|$;  $-|E|=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2+V(x)$ resulting in $\dot{x}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{m}(-|E|-V(x))}$. But I can't get the integral with Wolfram Alpha. Again it fails because it depends on some values of the variables. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

nephente's answer solves for the period. My answer is just made to make you see how to go on from the point you were, solving:

$$ e^{-2ax}-2e^{-ax}=\frac{E}{V_0} $$

We make the change $y=e^{-ax}$, which yields:

$$y^2-2y-\frac{E}{V_0} = 0$$

Second grade equation. Solve for $y$, and have in mind that $E/V_0$ is a negative number. It may give you complex solutions otherwise.

Comment: Oh, so when I get the two values for y I can just put it in $y=e^{-ax}$ and solve for x. I get it now. Thanks.